# How to backup ESXI host with failed drive

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a Dell R815 server running ESXi on a free licence.   I've got a small SSD as a single volume onto which I installed ESXi and a pair of 600GB Drives set up as a Mirror as a second volume, on which all my VMs are installed.

Now, it appears the SSD has failed! I'm seeing "Error:Timeout" in the web interface, and Rescan does nothing.  I even tried physically ejecting the drive and reinserting, on the basis that nothing could see it anyway, and a power cycle might help. This made no difference.

The server is still running, and all the VMs are working, as they are stored on the second volume.  However I'm loathe to restart the machine as I suspect it won't come back up again!

I can get in via ssh, and have tried to backup the configuration using the instructions found everywhere `vim-cmd hostsvc/firmware/sync_config`
`vim-cmd hostsvc/firmware/backup_config`
but I just get "A general system error occurred: Internal error" to both.

So... is there any easy way to backup the running configuration, prior to replacing the drive?  Is it a case of copying /etc across or is there more stuff lurking places that I need to find?
#Thanks

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. If the SSD where ESXi is installed and running from has failed then the host wouldn't be accessible and your virtual machines wouldn't be running. Can you clarify where ESXi is installed and running from?

Comment: It was definitely installed to the ssd.. I have no idea how or why its still running.. I was assuming it buffered to ram disc, based on the sync_config in the recommended backup process.

Comment: The trick is to backup your data **before the drive fails**. If the SSD is dead there's no use trying to read data from it. For serious use you need redundancy for the system drive as well - see the [help] for which scenarios are on topic here.

Comment: Yes I know....
Ended up re-installing and re-configuring.  There was nothing particularly obtuse about the existing config, so in the end it was simplest to rebuild, and all the VMs imported from the datastore without issue.
I'm going to look into making more regular backups now!!